# How to convert Decimal Floating-Point To 64-bit Hexadecimal using IEEE-754 Floating-Point convention

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, ieee-754

Are there any solutions to convert Decimal Floating-Point To 64-bit Hexadecimal using IEEE-754 Floating-Point convention?

I have decimal 4275451536 which needs to be converted into IEEE-754 Hexadecimal which is 41EFDAC6D2000000

Here it is an [online converter](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html), but I need to write it in programming language.

How to do this using Python ?

Comment: What's the Python type of your input? `float`?  `str`?  And what output are you looking for?  An integer?  Or a string giving a hexadecimal representation of that integer?  Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the underlying binary representation of an IEEE 754 binary64-format floating-point number, and show that binary representation in hexadecimal.

For obtaining the underlying bits, the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html) module is your friend.  The [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#struct.pack) operation lets you interpret the 8 raw bytes underlying the binary64 representation as a (byte)string of length 8, and the [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) operation will then let you re-interpret that string as a nonnegative integer (for example).  Once you've got the integer, it's easy to find the hex representation.  Here's a complete example for your data:

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = 4275451536.0
>>> bytes_of_x = struct.pack('<d', x)
>>> bytes_of_x
'\x00\x00\x00\xd2\xc6\xda\xefA'
>>> x_as_int = struct.unpack('<Q', bytes_of_x)[0]
>>> x_as_int
4751256679360757760
>>> hex(x_as_int)
'0x41efdac6d2000000'
```

It's not clear from your question whether you're starting with an actual decimal string, or a Python `float`;  the example above starts with a `float`.  If your input data takes the form of a decimal string, you'll want to convert it to float first:

```
>>> my_input = "4275451536"
>>> x = float(my_input)
>>> # ... rest of the code as before
```

Or all in one line, and using string formatting instead of the `hex` builtin to convert to a hexadecimal string:

```
>>> '{:016x}'.format(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', float("4275451536")))[0])
'41efdac6d2000000'
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Your answer is a working solution!!